# compare performance between spark and alteryx

Tags: apache-spark, alteryx

I know spark but new to  alteryx.Can anybody throw some light on my below question.
compare on basis of performance for spark and alteryx?

Also what exactly present in alteryx,that it  do ETL job in seconds(read)?

Comment: Can you be more specific?  Alteryx can talk to Spark so if you're hosting data on Spark, you can point Alteryx at it and basically have the same performance as Spark. It's probably easier to develop your ETL in Alteryx too, so perhaps from that angle it would be even faster. But for the most part you would have to just get a trial version of Alteryx and test for yourself.

Comment: @johnjps111 thanks for you response,how alteryx becomes more  faster compared to spark

Comment: I was suggesting similar performance but easier development, so while the end result would have the same performance, you might have the end result in production earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Alteryx uses all the "in memory" available from the desktop it's running on, so if you put it on a powerful desktop or virtual machine, it regularly outperforms SQL server, as they invested a ton in automatic performance tuning. I struggle to find scenarios where SQL could perform better without a ton of performance tuning. I can't say I can give an opinion as compared to Spark. I can say the nice thing about Alteryx though is that if you are dealing with true big data (TBs not GBs) and need to use Spark, you can use connectors and just execute your easy to follow workflow on enterprise grade resources, instead of on your desktop.